# How to SPOP from a list and SADD to another inside of lua scripting

Tags: redis, lua

I want to do the following in redis LUA scripting:

1. SPOP 1+ items from "source" set
2. SADD elements from #1 into "target" set

I'm using redis 5.

I have the below lua, but this is just for a single element:

```
local source = KEYS[1]
local target = KEYS[2]
local num    = KEYS[3]

local ele = redis.call("SPOP", "source")
redis.call("SADD", target, ele)

return "OK"
```

How can I update the above with:

1. handle 1+ elements using the passed in param KEY[3]
2. ensure if 0 elements were returned from POP, it doesn't try and add to target set.

Answer (score 2):

In Redis v5 and above this should "just work" due to the move to script effects replication as a default.

In v4 you'll have to execute `redis.replicate_commands()` before any random command in the script.

EDIT: per your edits and comment, here's an example:

```
-- uncomment the next line for Redis v4
-- redis.replicate_commands()


local source = KEYS[1]
local target = KEYS[2]
local num    = ARGV[1]

local elems = redis.call("SPOP", source, num)
if #elems > 0 then
  redis.call("SADD", target, unpack(elems))
end

return redis.status_reply("OK")
```

Comment: I need some help handling multiple items returned from SPOP, along with making it production worthy with checks for 0 items returned from SPOP. thanks!